# Comparing two lists and modifying one in Python

Tags: python, list

I have two lists `J` and `Cond`. For every `True` element in `Cond`, I want the corresponding element in `J` to be zero. I present the current and expected output.

```
J=[0, 2, 0, 6, 7, 9, 10]
Cond=[False, True, False, True, True, True, True]

for i in range(0,len(J)):
    if(Cond[i]==True):
        J[i]==0
print(J)
```

The current output is

```
[0, 2, 0, 6, 7, 9, 10]
```

The expected output is

```
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assignment is `=`, comparison for equality is `==`, so you'll want to do:

```
J = [0, 2, 0, 6, 7, 9, 10]
Cond = [False, True, False, True, True, True, True]

for i in range(len(J)):
    if Cond[i]:
        J[i] = 0

print(J)
```

Comment: How will the code change if ```J=[[0, 2, 0, 6, 7, 9, 10]]``` instead of ```J=`[0, 2, 0, 6, 7, 9, 10]```?

Comment: In that case, the `J[i]` is the entire list `[0, 2, 0, 6, 7, 9, 10]`, which means it will match with the first element of the second `False` and remain. If you don't want this to happen, consider flattening your list.

Comment: @isaacmodi123, if you have a multidimensional input list - correct your main question appropriately

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this in a cleaner manner, you can also do it with a list comprehension:

```py
J=[0, 2, 0, 6, 7, 9, 10]
Cond=[False, True, False, True, True, True, True]

J = [(0 if not c else j) for j, c in zip(J, Cond)]

print(J)
```

modifying lists while looping over them can be a bad idea, so this is not just less code, it is also better practice. In this case, for example, you could also specify `strict=True` in the zip to trow an error if the lists are not of the same size.

Answer (score 0):

For what you seem to be trying to do (setting all non-zero integers in a list to zero), having the Cond-list seems unnecessarily complicated. You could consider using this simple solution instead:

```
j = [0]*len(j)
```

Also consider using lowercase for your variable names, as that is the preferred way to do it in Python (quote from [PEP 8](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/), ie Python's "standard" style guide):

> Function and Variable Names
>
> Function names should be lowercase, with words separated by underscores as necessary to improve readability.
>
> Variable names follow the same convention as function names.
>
> mixedCase is allowed only in contexts where that’s already the prevailing style (e.g. threading.py), to retain backwards compatibility.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Good point, added reference to PEP8.

Comment: Although PEP 8 is good an efficient, it is not relevant to this post. Links would have to be documentation or other related resources that can be used to prove your answer is true.